# CORS error when querying backend The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

my svelte code is:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from "svelte";    
    let qdata = Object;
    let url = "";
    onMount(() => {
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/apisearch/".concat(window.location.href.substr(31));
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(dat => console.log(dat));
    }); //get query
    let h = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/apisearch/".concat(url);
</script>
{url}

<div class="grid justify-center rounded bg-slate-500">
    {#each qdata as result}
        <p>{result}</p>
    {/each}
</div>
```

The error I get is `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/apisearch/test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.`
My backend is built in rust with the rocket framework.  I am using sveltekit.

Comment: This is something you will have to fix on the backend/API side, by either relaxing CORS policy (wildcard) or setting it to specific domain origin(s). [Here](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/rust-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/) is a resource that might help you.